# Laravel 9 incorrect rate limit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I just installed Laravel 9 and Laravel Fortify. However, the rate limit for the login function is incorrect.

**FortifyServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
{
    Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
    Fortify::updateUserProfileInformationUsing(UpdateUserProfileInformation::class);
    Fortify::updateUserPasswordsUsing(UpdateUserPassword::class);
    Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);

    RateLimiter::for('login', function (Request $request) {
        $email = (string) $request->email;

        return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($email.$request->ip());
    });

    RateLimiter::for('two-factor', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->session()->get('login.id'));
    });
}
```

As you can see, it shows five requests per minute. However, whenever I tried to log in incorrectly after the first request, it kept giving me an error `429: Too Many Requests`. This is because it only allows me to log in one time.

I tried on both PHP versions, 8.0 and 8.1.2.

Update:

I also tried Laravel v8.

Dev environment: Laragon also tried with Laradock (docker) but still the same issue.

Comment: Does this only happen with Laravel 9 ?

Comment: I have same issue. Just downloaded Laravel 8

Comment: how are you attaching the rate limiters to the routes?

Comment: I did not attached the rate limiters to the routes. I just used the Fortify as is. The limiters was on the `FortifyServiceProvider`,

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact same issue and fixed it.

In my situation, I changed the default route names. `/login` became `/sign-up` and `/two-factor` became `/account-two-factor`.

So I changed the Rate Limiter names in the **FortifyServiceProvider.php** file.

```php
RateLimiter::for('sign-in', function (Request $request) {
    $email = (string) $request->email;
    error_log($email.$request->ip());
    return Limit::perMinute(50)->by($email.$request->ip());
});

RateLimiter::for('account-two-factor', function (Request $request) {
    return Limit::perMinute(50)->by($request->session()->get('login.id'));
});
```

I needed to change the **config/fortify.php** `limiters` array from

```php
'limiters' => [
        'login' => 'login',
        'two-factor' => 'two-factor',

    ],
```

to

```php
'limiters' => [
        'sign-in' => 'sign-in',
        'account-two-factor' => 'account-two-factor',

    ],
```

and also change my custom route names which I have in **routes/fortify.php** from

```php
$limiter = config('fortify.limiters.login');
$twoFactorLimiter = config('fortify.limiters.two-factor');
```

to

```php
$limiter = config('fortify.limiters.sign-in');
$twoFactorLimiter = config('fortify.limiters.account-two-factor');
```

My take-away are that the defaults should work out of the box and my mistake was that I renamed the `RateLimiter::for(...)` part and broke the keys from the config.